# Is there man command for bundle?

Tags: man, ruby

There is a command `bundle` in `ruby`.

I want use `man` command or similar function for `bundle`. Does it exist?
If there is it, I want to know how to look for separated command like `bundle gem`.

I can see it online, but I prefer to read it in command line.
http://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-gem.1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Definitely**, the `bundle-gem` online manual was created from the [bundle-gem.ronn](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/man/bundle-gem.ronn) file.  And `ronn` is a format (and program) meant to be formatted as a man page.

First let's get the files (for `bundler-gem` and `ronn`):

```
git clone https://github.com/bundler/bundler.git
gem install ronn  # this actually depends on mustache, rdiscount and hpricot
```

And create the man page:

```
$ /home/grochmal/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/ronn -r bundler/man/bundle-gem.ronn 
     roff: bundler/man/bundle-gem.1
```

(You probably have the gem path in PATH, but I added it here just in case.  Also `-r` stands for `roff` i.e. the format used for man pages)

And see the manpage:

```
man bundler/man/bundle-gem.1
```

If you want the manpage to show when you do `man bundle-gem` place it somewhere sensible and add that place to `MANPATH`.  For example:

```
mkdir ~/man{,/man1}
cp bundler/man/bundle-gem.1 ~/man/man1/
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:~/man
```

(Note the use of man sections here)

---

#### Extra notes

Since `ronn` uses `hpricot` you can use `ronn -5 <file.ronn>` to generate that web manual you were reading.

`gem` will run `ronn` for you, therefore if you installed `bundler` with `gem` you will have the manual page in `~/.gem/ruby/<version>/gems/bundler-<version>/man`.  Unfortunately `gem` does not follow the *nix convention of dividing man sections into directories (`man1`, `man2`, ...), therefore it may be troublesome to retrieve the man pages from `~/.gem` (using `MANPATH` isn't an option here).

If you do not have `MANPATH` set yet, then your system is using `/etc/man_db.conf`.  In that case you should set `MANPATH` as:

```
export MANPATH=`manpath`:~/man
```

Comment: A gem sometimes installs its own ronnified man pages. On my system, for instance, one can run `man -l /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/man/bundle-gem` .

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - Wow, I never noticed that.  Thanks, I'm wiser now.  I made an overhaul of the answer as well to add that info.